# Datediff on unknown hour interval - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have a dataset which shows a `datetimestamp` for both the start and end of an agent status and I am trying to capture the duration within that hour interval of that status by using a simple `datediff` function in SQL Server 2012.

This works perfectly as long as the status start and end time are within the same hour. However, in cases where the status starts at 8:37 and finishes 10:15, I am having a hard time inserting an hour interval to perform the `datediff` function.

In the scenario above, I would like the data to show 23 minutes in the 8 am interval, 60 minutes in the 9 am interval, and 15 minutes in the 10 am interval.

Comment: Please show us some sample data in a table along with the output you expect.

Comment: I don't understand what output you are expecting (three rows or just one number?). Perhaps you can just use _minute_ instead of hour, and divide by `60.00`

Comment: I'm not sure if posting a link to an external website is allowed here.. but I think this is what the OP is after - something similar to this

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174035/split-duration-hourly-depending-on-start-and-end-time

Comment: I can be done in so many ways depending upon your input data in table and format of output expected.given link can solve your problem.